# mPDF - bad background-image quality in Firefox PDF viewer

Tags: firefox, mpdf

I create a PDF (using php library mPDF) with a full size background image on the body tag:

```
body {
    background: url("..path/to/bg.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image-resize: 6;
    background-image-resolution: 300dpi;
}
```

It looks just fine in Chrome's, IE's and Acrobat's PDF viewers, but horrible in FF:
[image]

Any idea how I can handle this for Firefox?
I played with the CSS, using width and height, different resolutions, embedding as .svg, but to no success.

Comment: Same problem here.
Full page background is blurry and there is also a scale problem : width & height are only 25% of the page.

I think that there is no solution today, it looks like a pdf.js bug and we must wait for an update...

(At least you should have a message : this pdf is not displayed properly, or something...)

Comment: I looked in firefox nightly, the scale bug on printed pdf is fixed, bug the blurred background is still here. It's just a matter of time.

Comment: Scaling works fine for me. For now, I have created an absolute positioned image, set in the background via z-index. Working fine.

Comment: you didnt have a problem with the auto page break being triggered when using an image? i sure did, i couldnt make a full page background image & of course pdfjs was blurry... but eventually i saw the [size constraint](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=245) section in the manual which seems to finally work (full page size image without bugs)

Comment: The blurry is caused by the repeat property.

Comment: It is now 2018 - exactly 4 years later - and this still happens...

Answer (score 12):

It's caused by a bug in Firefox's `pdf.js` that manifests when PDF files were generated from mpdf with `background: no-repeat` on its HTML source.

As a work-around, removing the `no-repeat` property avoids the bug.

Answer (score 0):

locate the file 
`mpdf.php`

change 
`$this->_out(sprintf('/YStep %d',99999));`

to 
`$this->_out(sprintf('/YStep %d', 1024));`

and 
`$this->_out(sprintf('/XStep %d',99999));`

to
`$this->_out(sprintf('/XStep %d', 1024));`

These changes did work with me