# MPDF document and Image DPI problems

Tags: php, pdf, printing, dpi, mpdf

Background:
I am trying to render a business card at 300dpi using the mPDF library. The document has an image background which should fill the canvas and then have various text elements overlayed.

Dimensions:
The PDF document is set to 91mm x 61mm and is in Landscape format.

```
$pdf = new mPDF('utf-8', array(91,61), 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'L');
```

I have the resolution set in the config as follows;

`$this->dpi = 300;
 $this->img_dpi = 300`

I have create an image in photoshop, also at 300dpi to the same dimensions as the card (91mm x 61mm).

I have tried adding the image to the document inside a div using markup as follows:

```
$html .= '<div style="position: absolute; left:0; right: 0; top: 0; bottom: 0;width:100%; height:100%"><img style="width:100%; height:100%" src="/assets/images/bg.jpg"></div>';
```

When the PDF document is displayed, the image seems to be smaller than the document, ie, it is not scaled to fit the page. In fact the image only appears to fill approximately 55-60% of the canvas in X and Y directions.

When I save the PDF document and look at its properties inside Adobe reader it is confirmed to be the correct size of 91x61mm.

Has anyone had a similar problem or understand what is going on here?

I really need to be able to have a 300dpi image which will fill the page exactly.

I look forward to your suggestions.

Regards

James

Answer (score 1):

the css styles you have dont entirely match the ones in the manual's [recommendation](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=245) in the 'size constraint' section

in my case, i have a landscape image that's 11x8.5 inches 150dpi in photoshop, which is matched in mpdf as the page size, i separated the css for cleanliness

just in case, i specified any other mpdf values or css settings

so try something more like this code that is working for me, position the text with css & adjust the dpi/page size as needed:

```
$html = '
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    #bg {
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    #bg img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #text1 {
        top: 20%;
        font-size: 20pt;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #text2 {
        top: 60%;
        font-size: 16pt;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        color: #ddd;
    }
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="bg">
        <img src="bg.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="text1">John Smith</div>
    <div id="text2">555-5555</div>
</body>
</html>';

$mpdf = new mPDF('UTF8','Letter-L',14,'Arial',0,0,0,0,0,0);
$mpdf->dpi = 150;
$mpdf->img_dpi = 150;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$mpdf->Output();
```

there is of course an easier way to make a background... tell body or html to have a background image in css, but then you run into [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684792/mpdf-bad-background-image-quality-in-ffs-pdf-viewer) so it's not my first recommendation